# How to strip double quotes in this AWK single liner, and drop first record?

Tags: php, awk, text-processing

Trying to find a list of all unique manufacturers in my AWK code. I have it successfully extracting them from the CSV using the following and outputting to a linebreak delimited text file for future php import to Magento:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";ORS="\n";}a[$33]++==0 {print $33}' ./rsrimport/IMPORT.csv >OUTPUT.txt
```

which outputs this:

```
"manufacturer"
"5.11 Tactical"
"Advantage Arms"
"Advanced Armament Corp"
"Ultra Dot"
"American Classic"
"AccuSharp"
"Adams Arms"
"American Defense Mfg."
"Advanced Technology"
"A&G"
"Aimpoint"
""
"Arsenal, Inc."
"Allen"
"AmeriGlo"
"Apex Tactical Specialties"
"Armscor"
"Armalite"
"A.R.M.S., Inc."
"ASP"
```

What I want to do is threefold:

1. Strip the double quotes
2. Drop the first line (which is the header
       from the file)
3. Eliminate any blanks (lines with "")

Been struggling with this for a while, and read countless forums. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: considered doing it in php?

Comment: Actually, that was another avenue I considered. I was thinking about making a followup question based on that.

Comment: file — Reads entire file into an array, then loop str_replace for " (or in this case trim()) empty() for empty lines $array[0] for line 1. i never like mixing to many languages up

Comment: The issues there are is I need to run through the CSV, extract the 33rd fields unique values, and suck them into the array. Its been a long time since I coded straight PHP. When I get back from lunch I'll post up the PHP Code.

Comment: fgetcsv()\str_getcsv() would be the best start point then

Comment: @Dagon I added going the PHP route to a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `gsub` to substitute `"` and use `if` condition.

```
{x=$33; gsub("\"","", x);  if(x && FNR!=1){print x;}}
```

http://ideone.com/36IwCx

Comment: Final code, based on your input, was:
`awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";ORS="\n";}a[$33]++==0 {b=$33; gsub("\"","", b);  if(b && FNR!=1){print b;}}' ./rsrimport/IMPORT.csv >EXPORT.txt`
Had to change your a variable to b variable to keep from conflicting with the first a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sed -re '1d;s/"//g; /^( \t)*$/ d' temp.txt
```